# How to write short title chapter option in toc

Tags: context

In LaTeX, we can use short chapter title in table of contents or in header like this :

```tex
\chapter[short title]{My very long long long title}
```

How can we achieve that in ConTeXt ?

Comment: `\chapter[list=short title]{My very long long long title}`

Comment: Thank you for your answer. By the way,  for headertexts when I type `\getmarking[chapter]`, I get the long one. How to get the shorter ?

Comment: `\chapter[list=short title,marking=short title]{My very long long long title}`

Comment: @JairoA.delRio I think those comments could work as an answer.

Comment: I would recommend `\startchapter[list=..., marking=..., title=....] ... \stopchapter`